# Can I deploy a jar (without ear) on Wildfly 10, with the possibility of CDI?

Tags: jboss, cdi, wildfly-10

I have a jar which will be deployed on an Wildfly 10 (It's a Keycloak-Server) and I am forced to package it as a JAR.

Is it possible to use for example @Inject  or @Stateless in a JAR without the EAR-Structure?

Comment: You should be able to use CDI like that, what's not working for you? Make sure you have `beans.xml` there.

Comment: Thank you I forgot the beans.xml